# JaCoCo and Aspectj

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, jacoco

I've bean using JaCoCo in a maven multimodule project and want to add some AspectJ magic and I'm getting the following error during test run

Start java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException:

```
Error while instrumenting class de/../LoggingAspect.
```

Underneath this message the stack trace once more shows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing or invalid stackmap frames.
```

How can I use jacoco with aspectj?

Comment: is offline instrumentation with jacoco an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when using java 1.6.  aspectj compile-time weaving produced class files which jacoco found to be invalid.

The combination of `Java 1.7` + `aspectj 1.7.3` + `jacoco 0.6.3.201306030806` works for me.